# Azure Function web socket client

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there any way to have an Azure Function listen for events from a remote web socket and handle messages as their come over?

I have looked at the current documentation and samples but haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Web sockets are not currently an event trigger that is supported by Azure Functions. Your only option would be to have another application that listened to the web socket and placed messages on a queue or hit an HTTP triggered function, but at that point the listening application might as well handle the incoming message itself.

The documentation here shows the current list of supported function triggers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings